# Program stalls when running as a Windows service

Tags: pywin32, python.net

I have a python program calling a 3rd party .NET library. When running it as a Windows service, the program stalls calling a .NET function. The function never returns. When running the program from the shell, the program works as expected.

Any thoughts as to why this might happen? I thought maybe something related to threading? But still I can't think of why it might work from command line but not from a Windows service.

Any thoughts on how to go about it would be greatly appreciated.

Using `pythonnet` (for calling .NET code) and `pywin32` (for the service functionality)

Since it's a 3rd party library that I'm calling, I don't know anything about what the function that stalls does. There's a good chance it creates threads, but I don't know it for a fact.

Comment: I think that more information is needed in order to sort this out. However, windows services run as session 0 by default and can neither interact with the GUI nor start child processes. It could have to do something with that, hard to tell if you don't have access to the 3rd party code/logs.

Comment: It could also be that the 3rd party throws an exception which you don't catch properly. Did you make sure that you "hang" on the call?